# Trying to get style="margin-left:{{data}};" to work

Tags: html, css, angular, margin, ngfor

```
index.ts
bubbles: any [][] = [['80%','Meeting'],['20%','Meeting']]

index.html
<div *ngFor="let bubble of bubbles">
      <div class="bubble" style="margin-left:{{bubble[0]}};">
      </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to have the margin-left style use the data from the array bubbles[0].

The for loop gives ['80%','Meeting'] in that layout so I have tried to set the 0 element of that array to the margin-left style but this isn't working. Is there another way to do this process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `[ngStyle]` instead of `style`. documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgStyle-directive.html).

```
<div class="bubble" [ngStyle]="{'margin-left': bubble[0]}">
```

Comment: I get this error: Parser Error: Binding expression cannot contain chained expression at the end of the expression [{'margin-left': bubble[0]};]

Comment: @ThomasY sorry,  we have to remove `;` from the end of the expression.

Comment: @ThomasY use `,` to split them  such as `{'attr1': xx, 'attr2': yy}`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Pengyy's answser, you can also use

```
<div class="bubble" [style.margin-left]="bubble[0]">
```